# How to route all traffic through OpenVPN using Network Manager?

Tags: 15.04, network-manager, openvpn

I can successfully connect to my OpenVPN server from command line using `openvpn --config client.conf`. The client.conf file contains `redirec-gateway` directive to route all traffic through the VPN server. All this works fine.

Now, **how can I achieve the same result with Network Manager and nm-applet?**

I tried simply configuring the connection. It initializes correctly but doesn't route the traffic through the server. It's as if I ticked "Use this connection only for resources on its network" when I didn't.

It seems that when I connect from the command line, the VPN route is added at the top

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.10.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1024
```

but it's added as second when connecting from the applet

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
default via 192.168.10.5 dev tun0  proto static  metric 1024
```

This is on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid and OpenVPN 2.3.2.

Comment: Did you install a plugin for network manager to get openvpn to work?  If so, which one?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, network-manager-openvpn. OpenVPN works from the Network Manager, it just doesn't do the equivalent of redirect-gateway.

Comment: Hmm, on my Ubuntu 12.04 system, I also get slightly different results from the command line and nm-applet connection methods....but in my case the VPN is first in both cases.  I don't understand why they give different results though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't known how to set this option in `NM` but you can add script in `/etc/ppp/if-up.d/` to make default route to `ppp0` interface every time when go up. Make script called script with execute `permissions 755`

`sudo nano /etc/ppp/if-up.d/script`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "ppp0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo route add default dev ppp0


chmod 755 /etc/ppp/if-up.d/script
```

Try

Edit 1

If you have `tun0` interface then place script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`
and change interface name

`sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "tun0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo route add default dev tun0


chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

Comment: This is OpenVPN, not ppp. Will it work for any virtual network?

Comment: I edited my answer. Only is interface name matter and place of script . Yes will work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem on Ubuntu 15.04 and this solution works for me:

- Either remove all network interface (except lo) from /etc/network/interfaces so that it will be managed by the network manager or edit the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, change the line ***managed=false*** to ***managed=true*** and restart the network manager (`sudo service network-manager restart`)
- Get the name of the iface used as the default gateway.

  `> route
  Destination  Gateway       Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  default      fritz.box     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp60s0`
- Find out the uid for this interface and the uid for your vpn connection

  `> nmcli c
  NAME           UID                                   TYPE             DEVICE  ..... 
  Wired conne....3d7cfc99-dd28-45c1-87d8-5ec88b0b687c  802-3-ethernet   enp60s0 
  VPN France     2c5131c6-3d8e-4768-a67e-cbcc4f35db1f  vpn              -- 
  .....`
- Set the metric for current default interface to e.g. 2 and for the vpn device to 0

  `sudo nmcli connection modify uuid 3d7cfc99-dd28-45c1-87d8-5ec88b0b687c ipv4.route-metric 2
  sudo nmcli connection modify uuid 2c5131c6-3d8e-4768-a67e-cbcc4f35db1f ipv4.route-metric 0`
- Start the vpn connection via the network manager

- Route will now show something like this (*VPN-Gateway* is a placeholder for the VPN-Gateway's IP-address). That means that all traffic will be routed through the VPN server.

  `> route
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination  Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  default      VPN-Gateway     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
  default      192.168.220.1   0.0.0.0         UG    2      0        0 enp60s0`